# What does bandwidth mean?

Tags: r

I plotted density function in R and under the plot is number of bandwith. What does this number mean?

Comment: Well documented: e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation and http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/density.html

Comment: Typing `?density` gives a direct answer: "the bandwidth bw is the standard deviation of the kernel".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The bandwidth is a measure of how closely you want the density to match the distribution.

See help(density):

> bw    the smoothing bandwidth to be used. The kernels are scaled such
>   that this is the standard deviation of the smoothing kernel. (Note
>   this differs from the reference books cited below, and from S-PLUS.)

See also

> adjust    the bandwidth used is actually adjust*bw. This makes it easy to
>   specify values like ‘half the default’ bandwidth.

At least for me, bandwidth doesn't match any particular intuition, but you can see the effect of changing it:

```
set.seed(201010)
x <- rnorm(1000, 10, 2)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(density(x))  #A bit bumpy
plot(density(x,adjust = 10)) #Very smmoth
plot(density(x,adjust = .1)) #crazy bumpy
```

[image]

Comment: An intuitive explanation (in the bivariate case) is given on the GIS site at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/how-to-interpret-grass-v-kernel-results/1589#1589 (where "half-width" is synonymous with "bandwidth"). It would be no trouble to adapt this explanation to the univariate case.